# Does over-completing challenges serve any purpose?

Tags: golf-story

In Golf Story, you are allotted a certain number of strokes to complete various challenges throughout the game. In some of these challenges, (I suspect story-specific ones), once you meet your goal (3/3 shots on the green, for instance), you will get a SUCCESS message along with cash and experience.

On side quests however, after you complete your objective you can keep going with your allotted strokes. This can lead to a complete quest with 6 out of your required 3 shots made, for example. This also occurs in some non-golf minigames such as the disc golf challenges.

Does over-completing these challenges confer any extra monetary or experience benefit from the quest? Or is it simply letting you play out the remainder of the challenge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no reward for over-completing challenges in Golf Story.**

To test this, I started a new save file and played until I reached Wellworn Grove. I then saved the game and played through the Bunker Challenge four times.

Regardless of how many shots I made, I always earned the same reward: $3.85 and 30xp